# How many subsets of size at most $\log n$ does a set of size $n$ have?

Tags: combinatorics

I was reading [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=dominating%20set%20tournament%20graph&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http://pdf.aminer.org/001/093/420/on_finding_a_minimum_dominating_set_in_a_tournament.pdf&ei=3BeJUb-FCYSGjALKhIDwAw&usg=AFQjCNHMhnF8BOrNLHWtiU7pmHgVVNux8g&sig2=OBDUbDM5rNxwgBA6QnR21Q&bvm=bv.46226182,d.cGE) on an algorithm for finding a dominating set in a tournament graph.  The paper claims that an $n$-element set has $n^{O(\log n)}$ subsets of size at most $\log n$.  The paper doesn't offer any proof of this, and I don't know how to prove that this is true.

Is there a straightforward way to show this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it actually claims that an $n$-element set has $n^{O(\log n)}$ subsets of size at most $\log n$ (which is obviously true). The | sign appears to correspond to ^ in LaTeX.

Comment: Oh wow, I miswrote the original question.  That's definitely supposed to be $n^{O(\log n)}$.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we pull with replacement, there are $n^{\log n}$ possibilities for a draw of size $\log n$.  Pulling without replacement to get a subset will decrease the possibilities.  Then if we sum for the number of elements from $0$ to $\log n$ we get $\frac {n^{1+log n}-1}{n-1}\in  O(n^{\log n})$

Comment: My apologies... I wrote the wrong value in the question.  But thanks for this answer!

Comment: @templatetypedef:  new question answered

Comment: Beautiful... that was very straightforward.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but why do you have $n^{1 + \log n} \;$  in the numerator instead of just $n^{\log n}$. Isn't the exponent just the number of terms in your geometric series, that being $\log n$?

Comment: @kanso37:  I am summing a geometric series $1+n+n^2+\ldots+n^{\log n}$

Comment: Ah thanks of course. Maybe it should say "number of elements from $0$ to $\log n$" then. Assuming I am correct that what you mean by this is: adding up the number of ways of pulling without replacement $0$ elements, $1$ element, $2$ elements, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can write this number $\sum_{k=0}^{\log n} {n \choose k} \leq (\log n + 1) {n \choose \log n}$, and try to approximate this last term.

Comment: How would you approximate that term?  I was able to get to the point you're at now but am totally stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: There must be something more elegant, but using Stirling's approximation should probably get you somewhere.